# Designing an "updatable" static set for use with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, set

I have a need to create an immutable set of about 10,000 entries that will be "updated" (re-created) once a week. I've been reading up on the Executor framework for doing the updating, but I'm not sure how to achieve the end-to-end functionality while utilizing Spring. To be more descriptive:

1. There is a list of 10,000 ID numbers stored in a file on my server. The file is updated once every 3-4 weeks and grows in size (but will probably never exceed 20000 entries)
2. The method in my service that requires this list is called thousands of times per day, so I'd like to store the list in memory once instead of fetching it every time the method is called
3. I want to update the list that's stored in memory once a week by reading the file on the server and re-creating the set

In "Springless" Java, it seems I could create a class that has a static Set and a single threaded ScheduledExecutor that updates the set every 7 days. The class with the Set/update thread is instantiated once when my Service is started, and my "Service" class just grabs the set when required. (not sure if this is a good implementation or not)

What's the best way to obtain this functionality while utilizing Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to using some in-memory datastore like [Redis](https://redis.io/) together with [Spring Data Redis](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/) for storing your entries and having very fast read/write scenarios.

That said, for a Spring approach to your current design:

1. Use the `@EnableScheduling` and `@Scheduled` annotations for your jobs. A guide can be found [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/#initial)
2. Mark your service with the `@Service` annotation so that Spring will generate a bean for it during component scanning (make sure the package is visible)
3. Create a non static setter for your `Set` and let your scheduled job call it to update the set. Since your service is a Singleton (default Spring bean setting), you don't have to worry about the static set being changed in all instances of your services.